# How to center set of buttons into div with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to center horizontally a set of buttons into div.

My problem is that the buttons continues left aligned.

//css

```
.space-btn{
    margin-bottom:5px!important;
}
```

here is my markup:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                   <div class="btn-toolbar">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Histórico</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Reagendar</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Detalhes</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that btn in bootstrap used inside `btn-toolbar` are floated

[image]

so you may add this code :

```css
.space-btn {
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Histórico</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Reagendar</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Detalhes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LuizAlves you're welcome ;) you need always to pay attention to the styles of all the classes you add. You can use google console in order to see what's happening ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no big issue in code you have to change position of `text-center` class. this will come like this.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Histórico</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Reagendar</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Detalhes</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

There is a small change also in css which is

```
.space-btn{
  float:none!important;
}
```

Comment: so exactly like my answer

Answer (score -1):

Add text-center class to the button container.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="btn-toolbar text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Histórico</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Reagendar</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary space-btn" type="button">Detalhes</button>
                   </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```